# Problems with user arguments in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm currently trying to take user arguments (usually 2) that are text files, get the amount of characters, lines, and words from the text file and display them back. My code currently adds them all together instead of listing them separately for each file. How do I list the file name based on user arguments, and the amount of lines, characters and words for each file without adding them together? Thank you for taking time to read this.

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $user_files = @ARGV;
chomp($user_files);

my @parts;
my $word_count = 0;
my $total_words = 0;
my $line_count = 0;

foreach my $line (<>)
{
    @parts = split (/\s+/,$line);
    $line_count += (line =~tr/\n//);
    $word_count += length($line) + 1;
    $total_words += scalar(@parts);
}

for(my $i = 0; $i < 1; $i++)
{
    print "File name:",       @ARGV, 
        "\t\t Word Count: ",  $word_count, 
        "\t\t Total words: ", $total_words, 
        "\t\t Total lines: ", $line_count, 
        "\n";

}
```

Comment: you will need to fix the logic that does the counting. There are bugs in there.

Answer (score 5):

There are two basic things you need to change to enable this to work.

1. Use `$ARGV` - when reading across multiple files using `<>`, it contains the name of the current file
2. Store the data in a hash (that is keyed on `$ARGV`)

In this sample, I've retained all of your calculations (but I think you'll need to reconsider some of those) and made a few other changes to clean up your code a bit.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings; # better than '-w'

my %files; # Store all the data here

# While is better than foreach here as is reads the file one line at a time.
# Each line goes into $_
while (<>) {
    # By default, split splits $_ on whitespace
    my @parts = split;
    # By default, tr/// works on $_
    $files{$ARGV}{line_count} += tr/\n//;
    # I think this calculation is wrong.
    # length() has no relation to word count. And why add 1 to it?
    $files{$ARGV}{word_count} += length($_) + 1;
    # Addition imposes scalar context, no need for the scalar keyword
    $files{$ARGV}{total_words} += @parts;
}

# Print all the information in the hash
foreach (keys %files) {
    print "File name: $_",
        "\t\t Word Count: $files{$_}{word_count}",
        "\t\t Total words: $files{$_}{total_words}",
        "\t\t Total lines: $files{$_}{line_count}",
        "\n";
}
```

Comment: Perl doesn't insist you shorten the code as much as possible, so I would have kept the $line variable, as its clearer, better self-documenting code..

Comment: Fair point. You could use `while (my $line = <>)` and retain the `$line` variable on the following lines. That looks too cluttered to my eyes. But TMTOWTDI :)

Answer (score 2):

This line :

```
foreach my $line(<>)
```

Is taking input from STDIN. You need to do something like:

```
for my $file (@user_files) {
     open my $fin, '<', $file or die $!;
     while ( my $line = <$fin> ) {
         # count stuff
     }
     close $fin;
     # print counted stuff
}
```

Also note that if you want to take multiple filenames as args:

```
my $user_files = @ARGV;
```

will only take the first arg. You probably want:

```
my @user_files = @ARGV;
```

Also, the `chomp` on an arg is unnecessary.

In your script, you're counting all the files before printing. Which is good, but you probably want to store that data in an array or hash. That data structure might look like this :

```
$file_counts = [
    {
        $file_name1 => {
            characters => $characters,
            words      => $words,
            lines      => $lines,
        }
    },
    {
        $file_name2 => {
            characters => $characters,
            words      => $words,
            lines      => $lines,
        }
    },
];
```

Comment: Thank's kjprice! I'm sure this is obvious but I'm very new to Perl.

Comment: @JohnnyDiamond08 as imran said, your counting logic will need some work.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without declaring user_files as an array?

Comment: @JohnnyDiamond08 Yea, with references = `my $user_files = \@ARGV; for my $file (@$user_files) {...}`

Comment: @kjprice: `<>` doesn't just read from STDIN. It will also read from files passed on the command line. There's no need to explicitly open the files.